# node js express - querying the price field

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Im having trouble figuring out how to query the price. My current attempt is not working and im not sure what you have to type in the local host.

http://localhost:3000/priceSearch?

I have implemented - orderSearch.find({price:{$gt:400, $lt: 700}})

the price field in my mongodb is a number not a a string

Thank you:D

Here is my code:

**priceSearch.ejs**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/WishList';


router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var price = req.query.price;

    MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Unable to connect to the server", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Connection established...");
            var orderSearch = db.collection('orders');

            // find document who satisify price
            orderSearch.find({price:{$gt:400, $lt: 700}}).toArray(function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                } else if (result.length) {
                    res.render('priceSearch',
                        {
                            priceSearch: result,
                            title: 'Product price search',
                        }
                    );
                } else {
                    res.send("No documents found");
                }

                db.close();
            });
        }

    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
req.query.price;
```

i added a stupid var to it